Fivetran REST API get all connectors
I'm currently working on a project where I need to list all connectors across multiple groups in Fivetran. I've managed to retrieve all the groups successfully using the REST API, but I'm having trouble listing all the connectors.
This is how I get all groups:
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.fivetran.com/v1/groups"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json;version=2",
    "Authorization": "Basic yourkeyetc"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

parsed = json.loads(response.text)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))

But when I try to access https://api.fivetran.com/v1/connectors I get a 405 because that specific URL only allows POST? Any help is appreciated.
